# What is making system run faster & smooth?

Tags: performance

Below is the picture of system stats **(on desktop)** which i am using

[image]

& below is **(on laptop)**

- Intel® Celeron® Processor N3050
- 8gb ram
- 250gb SSD
- Integrated Graphics
- ubuntu 20.4 OS

Comparing performance, the desktop performs well & fast, smooth.

not sure how ?
any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129173/discussion-on-question-by-hamendra-sunthwal-what-is-making-system-run-faster-s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this website that compares the two processors](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Pentium-G2020-vs-Intel-Celeron-N3050/m3604vsm31154), the difference is most likely because of the processors. The Pentium ranks much faster than the Celeron.

However, there are both differences in hardware and software. The only way to gauge the performance of the hardware would be to install the same software on both computers. Conversely, the only way to gauge the performance of the software would be to install and test both versions of software on each computer individually.

Additionally, sometimes laptops have powersaving features like throttling when the pc is not plugged into an AC outlet. This may or may not be an issue here. There are ways to disable powersaving features to get more performance but that would be more appropriate for a separate question and answer.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the explanation.

Comment: what to consider (stats hardware) while selecting laptop to code/work ?
in order to get best working experience using ubuntu in laptop ?

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal One question at a time please. Someone else would probably have a better answer but remember to keep the question specific as possible.